# Git know the list of branches before cloning

Tags: git, github, branch, clone, remote-branch

Is there a way to know the list of branches a repository has before cloning?

I tried the following command, but it doesn't seem to work for me:

`git ls-remote git@github.com:Username/project.git`

Edit solution:

`git ls-remote http://www.github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia --h --sort origin "refs/heads/*"`

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean?

Answer (score 3):

In a single line, locally, `git ls-remote /url/of/the/upstream/repo` should list the remote HEADs and their associated branches without cloning anything.

For example, if you wanted to see the branches of [Shopify/react-native-skia](https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia) you would run `git ls-remote https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia.git` which should return [image: branches of /Shopify/react-native-skia]

Comment: it is the same command that I specified, I don't understand what changes?

Comment: Consider the following project: https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia

Comment: The result I want to get as names are these: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2l5J.png

Comment: git ls-remote https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia

Comment: I assumed git ls-remote [github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia](https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia) was different from git@github.com:Username/project.git because that would be email:username/project.git which is rather different than simply /url/of/the/upstream/repo

Comment: Speaking of which, your example git ls-remote github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia does return the HEAD branches and associated branches

Comment: Does it not work for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243930/discussion-between-ben-l-and-paul).

Comment: Ok, from this list I get I just want branches. So I want to exclude all `refs/pull/..` and `refs/tags/`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to exclude lines like that, if you need the data you could try making a bash script?

Comment: I tried like this: `git ls-remote http://www.github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia --h`

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html

Comment: But it's not working, nothing returns.

Comment: Ok, solution: `git ls-remote http://www.github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia --h --sort origin "refs/heads/*"`